# change text on website based if user is logged in or not

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

i want to show a logout button when the user is logged in
and if the user isn't logged i want to show  an login button. 
I work wit json token, so i ask if the token isn't null, because then I know that the user is logged in. 
But it doesn`t work. Please Help!

home.page.ts

```
admin = false;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private storage: Storage, private router: Router) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    if (this.storage.get('token') != null) {
        this.admin = true;
    } 
  }
```

home.page.html

```
 <ion-button *ngIf="admin==true">Logout</ion-button>
 <ion-button *ngIf="admin==false">Login</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your Code like this.

```
  admin = false;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private storage: Storage, private router: Router) {}


  async ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    let token = await this.storage.get('token');
    if (!token) {
        this.admin = false; //User is not logged in
    } 
    else{
        this.admin=true; //user is logged in
    }
  }
```